# Where is input JSON in express without body-parser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules, body-parser

I know about `body-parser` and what it does. I'm curious to know where is data in request while using `express`. In which format does is exist before `body-parser` parse input.

```
// parse urlencoded types to JSON
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

// parse some custom thing into a Buffer
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }));

// parse an HTML body into a string
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));
```

Where will be data if none of these is used? In which format will it be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty thoroughly covered in the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body).

> The request object that's passed in to a handler implements the ReadableStream interface. This stream can be listened to or piped elsewhere just like any other stream. We can grab the data right out of the stream by listening to the stream's 'data' and 'end' events.

Express is really applying extensions to the Node.js HTTP server features, including extending the native Request and Response objects.  Therefore, you can likewise treat the Express request just like a [native request object as well](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req)

Answer (score 1):

A POST request is made to a specific path (with optional query parameters).  The body of the request is where the POST data is put.  Express by default reads the headers of the request, but does not read the body of the request.   It is the body-parser middleware's job to read and parse that request body so that its data is easily available to you.

> Where will be data if none of these is used? In which format will it be available?

So, if you don't have the `body-parser` middleware installed or don't have a version of the middleware that matches the format of the data, then the body will still be in the incoming request stream, waiting to be read.  The `req` parameter to the request is a readable stream.  The data will be waiting to be read in that stream.

The format will be whatever the content-type header in the request says the format will be.  For a classic form post, it is typically `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but it can be set to other types such as `application/json`.  It is the requester who decides what content-type to set and then they must encode the data in the body according to that standard.

For things like file uploads, other content types such as `multipart/form-data` may be used.